# Name of Swift class when exposed to Objective-C code does not respect the @objc renaming

Tags: xcode, swift

Given a declaration of a Swift class like

```
@objc(NSFoo) public class Foo {
   public func bar() -> () {}
}
```

I would expect, from my reading of the documentation, that on the Objective-C side of things we would be able to refer to this class using the identifier `NSFoo`. This is not what seems to be happening for me. The generated definition in `ProjectName-Swift.h` is:

```
SWIFT_CLASS("NSFoo")
@interface Foo
- (void)bar;
- (instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

whereas what I would expect is

```
SWIFT_CLASS("Foo")
@interface NSFoo
...
```

I am using Xcode 6.0.1.

I missing something, or is this just a Xcode bug?

Comment: Did you actually tried and failed to instantiate it in Objective C as `NSFoo`?

Comment: @milos Yes. The compiler balks with `Use of undeclared identifier 'NSFoo'`

Comment: Just a note. I'd avoid using any of the already used class prefixes like NS, CA, UI, etc...

Comment: @Fogmeister Yup. This was just an example though.

Comment: This bug was fixed in XC7b4, though it’s still broken for extensions to @objc(NSFoo) classes.

Answer (score 23):

*Note: Things have change since this answer was first written - see updates at the end!*

Yeah, this does seam to be a bug... though, controlling Obj-C runtime names of methods does work:

Say we define a pair of minimal Obj-C and Swift classes that interact with each other:

**Foo.swift**

```
import Foundation

@objc(SwiftFoo)
class Foo { // inheriting from NSObject makes no difference in this case

    @objc(postcardFromSwift)
    class func postcard() -> String {
        return "Postcard from Swift!"
    }

    @objc(getMailInSwift)
    class func getMail() {
        if let hello = NSBar.postcard() { // NSBar is an Obj-C class (see below)
            println("Printed in Swift: \(hello)")
        }
    }
}
```

**NSBar.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSBar : NSObject
+ (NSString *)postcard;
+ (void)getMail;
@end
```

**NSBar.m**

```
#import "NSBar.h"
#import "ObjS-Swift.h"

@implementation NSBar
+ (void)getMail {
    // notice that I am not referring to SwiftFoo in spite of @objc(SwiftFoo)
    printf("Printed in Objective C: %s", [[Foo postcardFromSwift] UTF8String]);
}
+ (NSString *)postcard {
    return @"Postcard from Objective C!";
}
@end
```

If we now call their class methods, say, from `main.m`:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "NSBar.h"
#import "ObjS-Swift.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    // notice that I am not referring to SwiftFoo in spite of @objc(SwiftFoo)
    [Foo getMailInSwift]; 
    [NSBar getMail];

    return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);
}
```

This prints the following:

```
// --> Printed in Swift: Postcard from Objective C!
// --> Printed in Objective C: Postcard from Swift!
```

But it shouldn't have! `Foo` should only be visible to Obj-C as `SwiftFoo` since that is what `@objc(SwiftFoo)` is promising to do. Indeed, using `SwiftFoo` triggers the `Use of undeclared identifier` compiler error instead. The fact that this did work for method names, leaves little doubt that this is a bug. I am just amazed that you seem to be the first to ask about it! Plus one for that!

And yes:

```
// <#ModuleName#>-Swift.h
SWIFT_CLASS("SwiftFoo")
@interface Foo
+ (NSString *)postcardFromSwift;
+ (void)getMailInSwift;
```

... does seam to be inverted for the class name, yet this is how that macro works – see WWDC video [Swift Interoperability In Depth](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) (c. 45 min and c. 48 min into the video). The relevant documentation is [Exposing Swift Interfaces in Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH2-XID_0).

**Xcode 7 beta 4**

The issue is now fixed (thanks to @ScottBerrevoets for the comment).

**Xcode 7.1**

(thanks to @Pang for the comment)

```
@objc class C { } // error: only classes that inherit from NSObject can be declared @objc
```

Comment: In Xcode 7.1, compiler says: *"Only classes that inherit from NSObject can be declared @objc"*.

Comment: Is there a way to also define how a obj-c method signature should look in swift?

Answer (score 5):

Currently (in XCode8) this seems to have been addressed.

Defined in XYZLogger.h and XYZLogger.m

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

NS_SWIFT_NAME(Logger)
@interface XYZLogger : NSObject

+ (void)verbose:(NSString *)logString;
+ (void)debug:(NSString *)logString;
+ (void)info:(NSString *)logString;
+ (void)warn:(NSString *)logString;
+ (void)error:(NSString *)logString;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Used in objc like this:

```
[XYZLogger debug:@"Hi from objective C"];
```

Used in Swift like this:

```
Logger.debug("Hi from swift");
```