# Swift/Objective-C Crash: Swapped class initializers while debugging

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

**Summary**

I'm facing a severe issue in an Xcode project at work and would be grateful for any advice, hints or comments on how to further narrow down or solve this problem!

Since a week or two, our project crashes while debugging (on simulator and device) at random places where Swift classes are initialised or their types are used.

**Examples**

Here is an example how it looks:

[image: The exception with console information]

- The table view fails to recognize the ListSectionHeader's inheritance
- When printing it's type, a different class is returned
- The returned class of the `.self` is always an Objective-C class of our Core.framework

Another example, where a `super.init` call fails, because the debugger suddenly confuses the parent class to be of a different type:

[image]

- Sometimes it crashes directly, when a Swift class is initialised with a `BAD_EXEC_ACCESS`

**What we've tried**

Things we have noticed and tried so far:

- The crash disappears on release builds
- The issue disappears with enabled memory or thread sanitisers
- The issue happens on Xcode 12.4, 12.5.1 and Xcode 13.0
- We enabled "SWIFT_COMPILATION_MODE = wholemodule" which made the issue disappear for a while, but it has returned after more Swift code has been added to the project
- If we add or remove Swift code, the crash moves to a different class, as if a mapping table (??) of class names and types is moved (pure speculation here)
- So far I'm unable to reproduce the issue in a sample project

**Additional Infos**

A few things about our project:

- Xcode workspace with a few static frameworks
- Core-Framework with the majority of being Objective-C classes
- A UserInterface-Framework that is Swift-only and imports the Core-Module in many classes
- All of our frameworks are part of an umbrella framework that is integrated in a test application that we use for debugging

**Ending thoughts**

I have my suspicions, that we may accidentally trigger some kind of compiler optimisation bug, that has to do with our mixed Swift and Objective-C code base.

If anybody has any idea on how to narrow down this crash, or has seen these symptoms, I would be very grateful. Right now it prevents us from any development.

Comment: In the scenario when `po ListSectioner.self` yields odd class name in the debugger, can you inspect what will happen for `po NSClassFromString("ListSectioner")`. You may need to adapt for Swift class mangled name. Or set it explicitly in Swift class definition as in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132823/name-of-swift-class-when-exposed-to-objective-c-code-does-not-respect-the-objc with `@objc("YourCustomClassNameInObjCRuntime")`

Comment: @Kamil.S Thanks for the suggestion. I don't have those Swift-Classes exposed to Objective-C though, because they're never called from there. I only use Objective-C-classes in my Swift code. Therefor `po NSClassFromString("…")` just returns `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We haven't been able to identify the root cause of the issue, but we managed to avoid the crash/bug when we disabled our test plan in our app's scheme. We noticed this, when we created a new app target and everything worked. After re-configuring the target and scheme, the issue reappeared as soon as the UI-test plan was added.

Perhaps this strategy helps anyone with a similar problem.